# Javascript/Typescript Closure Problem - Returning an object's function as a variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, closures

I am still very confused about JavaScript/TypeScript closure after reading through a number of examples on the web.

Here is the code that I am having trouble with:

```js
let obj = {
  message: '222',  
  printMessage: function() {
    return this.message
  },
}

console.log(obj.printMessage()); // 222
let func = obj.printMessage;
console.log(func());             // undefined
```

When I run this code, I am getting error `Cannot read property 'message' of undefined`.

I know I can run `obj.printMessage()` directly, but that's not what I want to do. I want to be able to return the `printMessage` function as a variable and eventually get called by another function.

I feel that the problem is related to closure, I just don't know how to approach it.

Many thanks for your input.

===========================================

Update:

I found the solution to my problem after tinkering with the code for a bit longer.

Here is my solution.

```
let obj = {
  message: '222',  
  printMessage: function() {
    return this.message
  },
  getPrintMessage: function () {
      return () => this.printMessage()
  }
}

console.log(obj.printMessage()); // 222
let func = obj.getPrintMessage();
console.log(func());
```

I created another function to return an anonymous function that calls `this.printMessage()`. This way I can access the function from outside of the object.

Thanks for everyone's input.

Comment: Nothing to do with closure, everything to do with not setting *this* to the correct value. See [*How does the “this” keyword work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work?r=SearchResults&s=1|420.7930).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the wonders of the `this` keyword in JS.

The value of `this` is determined by how a function is called (runtime binding). In your example, `this` is a method on an object that doesn't have a reference.

You can use `call` or `bind` methods to bind the `this` value or in this case could also take advantage of getters and setters.

```js
let obj = {
  message: '222',
  get mess() {
    return this.message
  }
}

const currentMessage = obj.mess

// Both return the same thing

currentMessage
obj.mess
```